# Does sound pass through the dome from the Leomund's Tiny Hut spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, hearing

Does sound pass through the dome of force from the [*Leomund's Tiny Hut*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tiny-hut) spell? In other words, can people inside the dome hear sounds coming from outside?

The spell mentions that light does not pass through the dome of force (people outside cannot see inside), but does not mention sound.

My first guess is people making noise inside the dome can be heard by those outside. Additionally, loud noises from outside the dome could keep the occupants awake (preventing a long rest).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Sound passes through

The [dome](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Tiny%20Hut#content) stops “Creatures and objects” and “Spells and other magical effects” - sound isn’t one of those. There are no secret rules.

It also doesn’t say anything about light passing through. It says “The dome is opaque from the outside, of any color you choose, but it is transparent from the inside.”

Comment: Sound *can* be a magical effect, e.g. from Major Image or Thunderclap.  A DM would then have to decide which part was the magical effect, and which was just mundane air movement caused by the magical effect.  e.g. they might rule that the actual thunder damage couldn't make it in, but that you'd hear it if within the 100 ft radius for audibility.  (Which BTW seems insanely short, [less far than a creaking door in a dungeon](//rpg.stackexchange.com/a/108832/15436).  Maybe it's supposed to mean "over *any* background noise").  Or rule the magic effect is a point source triggering air movement.

Comment: The aforequoted text does in fact say whether light can pass: “The dome is opaque from the outside, of any color you choose, but it is transparent from the inside.”

Seems fairly unambiguous to me: light can pass from without to within, but not the reverse.